How can I replace the last occurrence of " before ] (text-manipulation)
I'm doing some text manipulation and I want to replace the last occurrence of " (with ", "four") before ] which could be in different lines. (this essentially adds a new item in the array)
e.g:
array = ["one", "two", "three"]
other_array = ["one", "two", "three"]
array = ["one", "two",
"three"]
array =
 [
   "one",
   "two",
   "three"
 ]
array = ["one", "two",
"three"
]

should become
array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
other_array = ["one", "two", "three"]
array = ["one", "two",
"three", "four"]
array =
 [
   "one",
   "two",
   "three", "four"
 ]
array = ["one", "two",
"three", "four"
]

P.S: -We are guaranteed to get a valid array so array = ["one", "two]", "three"] is invalid as strings inside the array follow this pattern [a-zA-Z0-9] so you are guaranteed to get that
-Also note that they are other arrays but the one i'm interested in is an array named "array" which is unique.
Tried sed
#this works for the first scenario:

sed 's/\(array.*"\)\([^"]*]\)/\1, "newItem"\2/' file.txt

# but couldn't figure out how to do this for scenarios #2 & #3


Is the input in any well know structured document format?

Yes, terraform.

Is this the only transformation you want, or do you also (possibly) want to remove newlines on the RHS of array assignment (i.e. make every array assignment a single line entry)?

A lazy approach here would be to use perl in slurp-mode:
perl -0777 -pe 's/"\s*\]/", "four$&/g'

With recent versions of perl (5.36.0 or newer), you can replace -0777 with -g.
To do it only for array declarations that start with array = [:
perl -0777 -pe 's/^\s*array\s*=\s*\[[^]]*"\K\s*\]/, "four"$&/gm'

Example:
$ cat file
array = ["one", "two", "three"]
other_array = ["one", "two", "three"]
array = ["one", "two",
"three"]
array =
 [
   "one",
   "two",
   "three"
 ]
array = ["one", "two",
"three"
]

$ perl -0777 -pe 's/^\s*array\s*=\s*\[[^]]*"\K\s*\]/, "four"$&/gm' file
array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
other_array = ["one", "two", "three"]
array = ["one", "two",
"three", "four"]
array =
 [
   "one",
   "two",
   "three", "four"
 ]
array = ["one", "two",
"three", "four"
]

perl -p is the sed mode where the code, here passed as an expression on the command line as an argument to -e like in sed is run for each record in the file.
By default, records are lines like in sed¹ (though include the line delimiter), but that can be changed with -0<octal-number> to specify the byte value of a different record delimiter¹ and when that number is above 0377 (the maximum possible byte value), the whole input is a single record (the slurp mode).
The equivalent of sed's pattern space is the $_ variable, and that's what the s/regexp/replacement/flags operates on by default like in sed.
\s is the equivalent of [[:space:]]³, $& the equivalent of sed's & (contains what is matched by the regexp) though note the \K which affects that as it indicates what is to be Kept from the match (what's matched after it).
The m flag causes ^ to match at the start of each line in the subject instead of just at the start of the subject.
Implementing a slurp-mode is possible in sed using a loop such as:
sed '
  :1
  $!{
    N
    b1
  }
  s/"[[:space:]]*\]/", "four&/g'

But note that in some sed implementations, the size of the pattern space is limited so that approach could be used only for very small file.
Doing the equivalent of the m flag would require extended regexps (not supported by all sed implementations yet)
$ sed -E '
  :1
  $!{
    N
    b1
  }
  s/((^|\n)[[:space:]]*array[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\[[^]]*")([[:space:]]*\])/\1, "four"\3/g
'


¹ Though the GNU implementation of sed supports a -z to change it to NUL.
² -0 for NUL delimiters, -00 for paragraph mode.
³ Except in perl what it matches is not dependant on the user's locale. And there are some sed implementations such as GNU sed that have copied it from perl.

Thanks Stéphane, but I would not like to use perl for that matter? is there a way to do this in awk/sed or something

@kyles why? Is your system from the 70s?

haha, I'm just not familiar with it, but maybe this is an opportunity to learn about it?

the global flag in sed isn't working, it's just changing the first occurrence, any reason for that?

@kyles, works fine for me on the sample input with GNU sed 4.0 (not that there would be anything GNU-specific in there).

Ok it works, sorry, and thanks for the help!

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, \< word boundary, and \s shorthand for [[:space:]]:
$ awk -v RS='"\\s*]' '{ORS=(/\<array\s*=/ ? "\", \"four" : "") RT} 1' file
array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
other_array = ["one", "two", "three"]
array = ["one", "two",
"three", "four"]
array =
 [
   "one",
   "two",
   "three", "four"
 ]
array = ["one", "two",
"three", "four"
]

The above reads 1 " ]-terminated section of input at a time and so assumes that no such section of your input is too massive to fit into memory.
Using any awk you could do something similar by reading the whole of the input file into memory first:
$ cat tst.awk
{ all = all $0 ORS }
END {
    while ( match(all,/"[ \t\n]*]/) ) {
        $0 = substr(all,1,RSTART-1)
        rt = substr(all,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        ORS = (/(^|[ \t\n])array[ \t\n]*=/ ? "\", \"four" : "") rt
        print
        all = substr(all,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    printf "%s", all
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
other_array = ["one", "two", "three"]
array = ["one", "two",
"three", "four"]
array =
 [
   "one",
   "two",
   "three", "four"
 ]
array = ["one", "two",
"three", "four"
]


Using yj by Stephen Levine, which is a command line parser for various formats, including HCL, which is the structured format that Terrafrom configuration files uses, we can transcribe the configuration from HCL to JSON.  We may then use jq to modify the JSON, adding to the array array.  With a second pass with yj, we may then translate the file back to HCL:
$ yj -cj <file | jq '.array += $ARGS.positional' --args four five six | yj -jc
"array" = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]

Since we're using tools that are aware of the structure of the documents and of what values need to be handled specially in strings etc., this method also supports adding values containing double quotes and newlines.  Double quotes will automatically be escaped and literal newlines replaced by \n (and tabs by \t).

Would that keep the same structure of the array?

@kyles The array's structure will not be changed (apart form the obvious addition of one or more elements). The way it is formatted may change. This should not matter to any parser reading the file though.

Ok, I want to keep the same format as the input, so this wouldn't be a solution but it surely is if we don't take into care about format

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
~$ raku -e 'slurp.subst(:global, /^^ array \s* \= \s* <( ( \[ \s* ) ( .+? ) ( \s* \]) /, { "$0$1, \"four\"$2" } ).put;'

#OR:

~$ raku -e 'slurp.subst(:global, /^^ array \s* \= \s* <( $<pre> = [ \[ \s* ]  $<core> = [ .+? ]  $<post> = [ \s* \] ] /, { "$<pre>$<core>, \"four\"$<post>" } ).put;'     

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. It features a powerful Regex engine and various newer methods/functions. Above, the file is slurped all-at-once into memory, then you substitute (globally): within the / … / matching-domain, you look for ^^ start-of-line elements beginning with the word array. From there you match characters and \s whitespace, which includes newlines (vertical whitespace).
Raku's <( … )> capture-markers drop anything outside from the match-object (similar to Perl's \K). Here, only the <( marker is required. First answer: numbered captures within the match-object are accomplished with ( … ) parens, with numbering starting from $0, $1, $2, etc. Second answer uses named captures. Finally, you output the captures in the desired order, with the new element inserted.
Sample Input:
array = ["one", "two", "three"]
other_array = ["one", "two", "three"]
array = ["one", "two",
"three"]
array =
 [
   "one",
   "two",
   "three"
 ]
array = ["one", "two",
"three"
]

Sample Output (1):
array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
other_array = ["one", "two", "three"]
array = ["one", "two",
"three", "four"]
array =
 [
   "one",
   "two",
   "three", "four"
 ]
array = ["one", "two",
"three", "four"
] 


Finally (and this is entirely your choice), the advantage of moving to a more full-fledged programming language is the skills you gain in parsing text and storing in data-structures can be applied to a wide variety of problems (not just Terraform files). Below, a fairly simple 3-statement parser in Raku that takes each entry, and stores it in an "array-of-key/values" (wherein the values are also an array). The fourth statement appends the new value you want:
~$ raku -e 'my @a = slurp.comb(/ .+? \]\n /); 
            @a.=map({ $_.trans(/\s/ => "").trans("[\[\]]" => "") }); 
            @a = do for @a.map(*.split("=")) { .[0] => .[1..*].split(",").Array }; 
            for @a { .value.append: q["four"] if .key eq "array" }; 
            .say for @a;'  file

Sample Output (2)
array => ["one" "two" "three" "four"]
other_array => ["one" "two" "three"]
array => ["one" "two" "three" "four"]
array => ["one" "two" "three" "four"]
array => ["one" "two" "three" "four"]

https://docs.raku.org/routine/slurp
https://docs.raku.org/type/Str#method_subst
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org

Unless I misunderstand your problem, why not simply replace every ] by ,"four"]
$ sed 's/]/\,"four"]/' 775928 
array = ["one", "two", "three","four"]
other_array = ["one", "two", "three","four"]
array = ["one", "two",
"three","four"]
array =
 [
   "one",
   "two",
   "three"
 ,"four"]
array = ["one", "two",
"three"
,"four"]


In the original version of the question before Ed modified it, the OP was somewhat specific as to how the whitespace was to be preserved. Whether that actually does matter or not is a separate question. And whether all ] or all array assignments should be processed is also not clear in the question.

Let' hope we get some clarification from OP.
